# AngularJS with Apache Tiles

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, apache-tiles

I use Spring MVC and AngularJS for my project. Can AngularJs **$routing** and ngView be used instead of **or** together with the **Apache Tiles** framework? As far as I can see using $routing and ngView we create templates and reuse them in a singlePage application.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, AngularJs' routing can be use instead of tiles. Also you can use together, but after it may broke singlepage app idea.

In tiles you probably use jsp files. So jsp files compiling in server-side , and serving as html file in client side via browser.

In angular also you can create base layout. And like tiles' layout `extend` ability , with `ng-include` you can include your other views your `ng-view` htmls. And when route another page ng-view will refresh included area(Also there are  some third party plugins/frameworks on AngularJs about it.Take a look [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). It provides nice nested views.).

In Angular way `commonly` no need to get html from serverside(this situation may change depending on the other situations. To make singlepage no need.). So you will need to convert your controllers which returns `ModelAndView` object to Map(as an example) to return `json`. At this time routing will be achieved by angularJs' routes. After these refactorings , you will have a singlepage application. Or you can make `hybrid-singlepage`(some pages have too many event so you van start with that pages to make single page to reduce workload) So It will reveal workload depends on your application's size.