# Can AngularJS substitute Apache Tiles and taglibs?

Tags: angularjs, html, jsp, taglib, apache-tiles

I was reading this question without answers: [AngularJS with Apache Tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981102/angularjs-with-apache-tiles).

So I thought, can AngularJS substitute Apache Tiles and taglibs? Because with AngularJS you can create a single page application and reusable components, whereas Apache Tiles and taglibs can make the same job, but using a lot of XML and less HTML and it is hard to improve the manipulation of HTML elements with the use of JavaScript and the user experience with your application making effects, animations. Instead of, the use of Apache Tiles and taglibs allows a faster development of the application.

Comment: neither the browser nor angular care how the html gets delivered

Comment: but taglibs care about the html component attributes, each attribute from the html element is a new attribute in the taglib file.

Comment: really not clear what you are trying to do or what your concern is

Comment: One is server-side, other client(browser)-side